# Inputmask oncomplete without JQuery

Tags: javascript, validation, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I set mask:

`<input class="form-control" type="text" data-inputmask="'alias': 'email'">`

and call inputmask for multiple elements:

```
let els = document.querySelectorAll("input");
Inputmask().mask(els);
```

How I can set `oncomplete` event after? I try like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].inputmask['events']['oncomplete'] = function() {
        console.log('Uuuu')
    };
}
```

But it's not work :(

Code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phhg13px/3/)